# How to Integrate the https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ into the django application?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

- Get posts from JSON placeholder. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
- Get posts details from JSON Placeholder. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
- Get Comments from JSON Placeholder. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments

Answer (score 0):

Try to use request to call the api
https://www.w3schools.com/python/module_requests.asp
You can use serialize to integrate

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `jsonplaceholder` API from your DRF views. The example is below. It is using the `requests` package.

```py
# views.py
import requests
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class GetPostsList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        r = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        return Response(r.json())

class GetPostDetails(APIView):
    def get(self, request, post_id, format=None):
        r = requests.get(f"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{post_id}")
        return Response(r.json())
```

```py
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import GetPostsList, GetPostDetails

posts_urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^posts/$", GetPostsList.as_view()),
    url(r"^posts/(?P<post_id>\w+)/$", GetPostDetails.as_view())
]
```

You need to add URLs to your main URLs. Below are screenshots from a working example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: how to solve this?https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments

Comment: how to get this?https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments.. At first get this from view then how to use this on html template?